# How do I assign a variable to a specific function output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small project designed to help me learn python, although I can't find how to do this one thing. I want to assign two different variables to two different outputs of one function: e.g.

```
my_input1 = code_chooser()
my_input2 = code_chooser()
```

and code_chooser() does this:

```
def code_chooser():
    ect. ect. 
    if foo1 == 1:
        return my_input1
    elif foo1 == 2:
        return my_input2

    if foo2 == 1:
        return my_input1
    elif foo2 == 2:
        return my_input2
```

And this is in an instance where foo1 == 1 and foo2 == 2.

I can't see how to put two different variables from the same function into my_input1 and my_input2, and from what I know, in my situation and code, they need to be in the same function.

Comment: Is `code_chooser` a pure function? In other words, is `foo` a global or a local variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are actually asking. Are you asking how you can return two item from your function at the same time and store those two items in two variables?

Comment: It would help us know what's going on if you post a [mcve]. Code containing [`ect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroconvulsive_therapy) doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass arguments to a function? `my_input1 = code_choose(1, 2)` after defining `def code_chooser(foo1, foo2): ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `foo1` happens to be `1` or `2`, then the function will return `my_input1` or `my_input2`, that's the end. So unless `foo1` is neither `1` nor `2`, you may never get the proper value of `my_input2` by `my_input2 = code_chooser()`.

If... I'm not misunderstanding you, you may try this(though it's pretty low efficiency... but easy to understand):

```
def code_chooser():
    '''ect. ect. '''
    returnValue = []
    if foo1 == 1:
        returnValue.append(my_input1)
    elif foo1 == 2:
        returnValue.append(my_input2)

    if foo2 == 1:
        returnValue.append(my_input1)
    elif foo2 == 2:
        returnValue.append(my_input2)
    return returnValue
```

And use that:

```
my_input2, my_input2 = code_chooser()
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're saying. That completely slipped passed me, the fact that return ends the function. Will implement and test now.